# Whats the best way to override a block class in magento2

Tags: magento2, overrides

1) Use preference in di.xml and add new methods or do changes

2) Or create a new class which extends the actual class and attach the new class to your phtml.

Lets suppose you want to extend `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Listproduct` then you create a class like `Vendor\Module\Block\Product\Listproduct` and 
change here

```
<block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\Listproduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
```

Comment: i will go with the second approach. Its much more flexible. Plugins wont work here as i needed a new method.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than extend block use Plugin

There is three type of plugin

- Before plugin
- After plugin
- Around plugin

For more info please refer [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to override a block would be a plugin, but note that a plugin can not be used on following:

1. Final methods
2. List item
3. Non-public methods
4. Class methods (such as static methods)
5. __construct
6. Virtual types
7. Objects that are instantiated before `Magento\Framework\Interception` is bootstrapped.

**Reference -** https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html